# Debian/Ubuntu - Is there a man page listing all the version codenames/numbers?

Tags: debian

I sometimes forget the version numbers and codenames from Debian.
Sure, `lsb-release -a` or `cat /etc/os-release` prints a well formatted information regarding the current system I logged in, but:

**Is there a manpage or help document that lists all previous versions?**

(Ideally it's something "native", so no tool to install. And something relatively easy to remember, so no `curl`ing a webpage)

I didn't find a `man`-page and thought I might find something in in `/usr/share/doc` but unfortunatley not.

What I did find, was a python file, that gives:

```
grep 'Description: Debian' /usr/share/python-apt/templates/Debian.info
Description: Debian 11 'bullseye'
Description: Debian 10 'buster'
Description: Debian 9 'stretch'
Description: Debian 8 'jessie'
Description: Debian 7 'Wheezy' 
Description: Debian 6.0 'Squeeze' 
Description: Debian 5.0 'Lenny' 
Description: Debian 4.0 'Etch'
Description: Debian 3.1 'Sarge'
Description: Debian current stable release
Description: Debian testing
Description: Debian 'Sid' (unstable)
```

which is cool as a workaround, but dependent on the `python-apt` package to be installed and thats not what I was going for.

EDIT:

Thank @Gilles for finding `/usr/share/distro-info/debian.csv` (and ubuntu.csv)
This file is nearly perfect, it even contains the dates of creation,release and "endoflive for LTS", e.g.:

```
...
9,Stretch,stretch,2015-04-25,2017-06-17,2020-07-06
...
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's no `man page`:

```
find /usr/share/man -exec zgrep -li 'Wheezy|Potato' {} + 2>/dev/null
```

There's no *match*.

### One way, using just one `awk`:

```
awk -F, '{print $1, $2}' /usr/share/distro-info/debian.csv
version codename
1.1 Buzz
1.2 Rex
1.3 Bo
2.0 Hamm
2.1 Slink
2.2 Potato
3.0 Woody
3.1 Sarge
4.0 Etch
5.0 Lenny
6.0 Squeeze
7 Wheezy
8 Jessie
9 Stretch
10 Buster
11 Bullseye
12 Bookworm
13 Trixie
 Sid
 Experimental
```

For `Ubuntu`:

```
awk -F, '{print $1, $2}' /usr/share/distro-info/ubuntu.csv 
version codename
4.10 Warty Warthog
5.04 Hoary Hedgehog
5.10 Breezy Badger
6.06 LTS Dapper Drake
6.10 Edgy Eft
7.04 Feisty Fawn
7.10 Gutsy Gibbon
8.04 LTS Hardy Heron
8.10 Intrepid Ibex
9.04 Jaunty Jackalope
9.10 Karmic Koala
10.04 LTS Lucid Lynx
10.10 Maverick Meerkat
11.04 Natty Narwhal
11.10 Oneiric Ocelot
12.04 LTS Precise Pangolin
12.10 Quantal Quetzal
13.04 Raring Ringtail
13.10 Saucy Salamander
14.04 LTS Trusty Tahr
14.10 Utopic Unicorn
15.04 Vivid Vervet
15.10 Wily Werewolf
16.04 LTS Xenial Xerus
16.10 Yakkety Yak
17.04 Zesty Zapus
17.10 Artful Aardvark
18.04 LTS Bionic Beaver
18.10 Cosmic Cuttlefish
19.04 Disco Dingo
19.10 Eoan Ermine
20.04 LTS Focal Fossa
20.10 Groovy Gorilla
21.04 Hirsute Hippo
21.10 Impish Indri
22.04 LTS Jammy Jellyfish
22.10 Kinetic Kudu
23.04 Lunar Lobster
```

### Another way:

```
xidel -se '//div[@id="toc"]/ul//li//li/a' \
    https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian_version_history | 
    cut -d ' ' -f2-
```

or

```
curl -sL https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian_version_history |
     xmlstarlet format -H - 2>/dev/null |
     xmlstarlet sel -t -v '//div[@id="toc"]/ul//li//li/a' - |
     cut -d ' ' -f2-
```

## output

```
Debian 1.1 (Buzz)
Debian 1.2 (Rex)
Debian 1.3 (Bo)
Debian 2.0 (Hamm)
Debian 2.1 (Slink)
Debian 2.2 (Potato)
Debian 3.0 (Woody)
Debian 3.1 (Sarge)
Debian 4.0 (Etch)
Debian 5.0 (Lenny)
Debian 6.0 (Squeeze)
Debian 7 (Wheezy)
Debian 8 (Jessie)
Debian 9 (Stretch)
Debian 10 (Buster)
Debian 11 (Bullseye)
Debian 12 (Bookworm)
```

Comment: interesting. sure, I could also use some curl and sed magic or a perl/python expression. But remembering and construct this complex statement is maybe not that easy, if you're in the need to find out. I adjusted my question to reflect this.

Comment: You could create an alias

Comment: `/usr/share/distro-info/debian.csv` is perfect for this, thanks!

Comment: yeah, exactly! a csv file with all the infos, that already enough for me. maybe I searched on an to old machine and there it wasn't present. I can't tell for debian8, but on debian7 this file didnt exist. But I checked debian9,10,11 and the `debian.csv`/`ubuntu.csv` files where existent, even though the "distro-info" or "distro-info-date" is (and surely never was) installed. (dpkg -S /usr/share/distro-info/debian.csv > distro-info-data)

Comment: @MacMartin `python3-apt` depends on `distro-info-data`, that’s why you have the CSV file.

Answer (score 11):

As Gilles Quenot says, there’s no man page with this information; however the `distro-info` package provides a command which can show you this:

```
$ distro-info -af
Debian 1.1 "Buzz"
Debian 1.2 "Rex"
Debian 1.3 "Bo"
Debian 2.0 "Hamm"
Debian 2.1 "Slink"
Debian 2.2 "Potato"
Debian 3.0 "Woody"
Debian 3.1 "Sarge"
Debian 4.0 "Etch"
Debian 5.0 "Lenny"
Debian 6.0 "Squeeze"
Debian 7 "Wheezy"
Debian 8 "Jessie"
Debian 9 "Stretch"
Debian 10 "Buster"
Debian 11 "Bullseye"
Debian 12 "Bookworm"
Debian 13 "Trixie"
Debian  "Sid"
Debian  "Experimental"
```

More explicitly, `debian-distro-info` lists Debian releases, `ubuntu-distro-info` lists Ubuntu releases. `distro-info` defaults to whatever is appropriate for the distribution you’re using.

Comment: Not installed by default on my Debian 11. Require `distro-info` package. Nice way !

Comment: Yes, it’s not installed by default, that’s why I explicitly named the package ;-). Note that the CSV file you used comes from the `distro-info-data` package.

Comment: Never knew they were named after *Toy Story* characters lol

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- yes, see [Linux Debian codenames](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/222394/86440).

Answer (score 1):

additional to the other excellent answers, I now also found another another way via the gpg keyrings (strange, that `ack` didn't found this, but `grep` did)

This should work also on older machines as the gpg keyrings should be available everywhere:

```
gpg /usr/share/keyrings/debian-archive-keyring.gpg |grep uid 
gpg /usr/share/keyrings/debian-archive-removed-keys.gpg |grep uid  # on the debian7 machine I tested, I had to leave out the "grep uid"
```

(for ubuntu this doesnt seem to work, as the keyrings are differently structured)

Comment: `gpg: WARNING: no command supplied.  Trying to guess what you mean`

Comment: @DennisWilliamson - is that the only output? Indeed, gpg prints this warning when you don't specify an option. But it's just a warning, not an error. Running `gpg /usr/share/keyrings/debian-archive-keyring.gpg` on the console (I used bash) should print the strings nevertheless. I find the gpg options confusing and unfortunately I didn't find the correct on to list the keys in the file.

Comment: No, there are three messages about Automatic Signing Keys, but nothing about Ubuntu release versions or names. If I omit the `grep` there are a few `pub` entries. I also checked the removed and master files and found nothing.

Comment: my bad ... for ubuntu it seems like the keyrings are differently structured. sorry, will correct my answer :/

Answer (score 0):

Open a web browser (I assume you already have one installed) and visit https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian_version_history .

Comment: Thanks for your input, but this wasn't exactly the direction the question was headed. But rather how to find that information on a host natively (although I didn't specify "console only". There are times when you don't have a gui, and therefor no web browser installed - or times when internetacces is blocke and even w3/lynx/...-browser couldnt help)